# Selenium - How to increase extension load time in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, exception, selenium-chromedriver

**In the code trying to add a Metamask extension to Chrome browser**

```
chop = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

EXTENSION_PATH = r"C:/Work/Selenium testing/extension_10_8_1_0.crx"
chop.add_extension(EXTENSION_PATH)

CHROME_PATH = r"C:/Work/Selenium testing/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = CHROME_PATH, chrome_options = chop)
```

**But I'm getting an Exception:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 
failed to wait for extension background page to load:
 chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background.html
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
```

And after that i can see for a moment that extension page is opening. Like it needs 10-13 seconds to open but I'm getting this Exception... **How could I increase that waiting time?**

*By the way sometimes it opens, in about 1 to 15 case, but this is not what I need. Thanks.*

Comment: Try out: ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); options.addArguments("load-extension=C:/Work/Selenium testing/extension_10_8_1_0.crx");

Comment: @Slybot
I'm getting a windows error saying "unable to load manifest file from C:/Work/Selenium testing/extension_10_8_1_0.crx"

Note that this is not mine extension